# Calling Perl Script from Python With Argument

Tags: perl, subprocess, python-2.6

I am working on Python 2.6.6.I looked at various examples but I am not able call perl script in Python with arguments. Perl takes couple of arguments and display it.I am new to both Perl and Python and might me missing some basic thing. I am able to call perl script without giving any argument but once I try giving any argument,It's not calling the perl script

Python :test.py

```
 import subprocess
 import shlex
 p=subprocess.Popen(['perl','start.pl','1','2'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Perl :start.pl

```
use strict;
print "Called::\n";
my $name="$ARGV[0]";
print "$name\n";
my $next_name=$ARGV[1];
print "$next_name\n"
```

I am not sure how does perl takes the argument from python.Can someone please advice me where am I going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one more step:

```
print(p.stdout.read())
```

The output of the Perl process is stored in the object `p.stdout`, not written to the console.

Comment: Right . . . . .